# CoffeeScript doesn't compiles with Sinatra AssetPack

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sinatra, sinatra-assetpack

I'm using Sinatra AssetPack to manage assets in modular Sinatra application. It works great with JS files, but doesn't compiles CoffeeScript.

I've added line `js :app, ['/js/app.coffee']` into AssetPack conf at *app.rb*, just like in AssetPack readme on Github. Somehow `<script src='app.coffee'></script>` appends to *index.slim*, but file isn't accessible.

Gem coffee-script is listed in Gemfile, Node and coffee-script npm package are installed.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config line should be `js :app, ['/js/app.js']` in spite of file actually is *.coffee*.